# Gevent support in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, gevent

I was trying to install and use Gevent in Python3.4 after successfully using it with Python2.7. However using Python 3 I am getting a error at import itself. Is it not supported still in python3?

Using gcc 4.9 and installed using `pip3 install gevent`.

```
import gevent
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/gevent/__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from gevent.hub import get_hub, iwait, wait
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/gevent/hub.py", line 289
    except Exception, ex:
```

Comment: I installed the latest development version as described in https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gevent/1.1b5 and I could proceed

Answer (score 1):

`except Exception, ex` is Python 2 syntax, it should be `except Exception as ex` in Python 3. It looks like the Gevent package is indeed not properly prepared for Python 3.