# /gevent/hub.py: except Exception, ex: SyntaxError

Tags: python, pymongo, telegram, pymongo-3.x

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
    from bot import bot
  File "/root/musicbot/bot.py", line 7, in <module>
    from database import db, text_search
  File "/root/musicbot/database.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pymongo
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/__init__.py", line 92, in <module>
    from pymongo.connection import Connection
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/connection.py", line 39, in <module>
    from pymongo.mongo_client import MongoClient
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 46, in <module>
    from pymongo import (auth,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pymongo import thread_util
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/thread_util.py", line 31, in <module>
    from gevent.lock import BoundedSemaphore as GeventBoundedSemaphore
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gevent/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    from gevent.hub import get_hub, iwait, wait
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gevent/hub.py", line 282
    except Exception, ex:
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: The obvious is to check all modules involved are Python 3.5 versions.  Please format the output correctly, as you have pasted it is very difficult to read.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gevent support in Python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32734066/gevent-support-in-python3)

Answer (score 0):

You are using a Python package which is for Python 2.x and uses old `Exception` syntax (gevent.hub).

You need to upgrade the violating module to Python 3.x compatible version.

If this is not possible then you need to deploy your application on Python 2.x.

Comment: This script doesn't start on python2.X

Comment: If there is a Python 2.x error then please edit your question and add it there, so I don't need to guess what is says on your monitor :)