# SyntaxError in gevent on Python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.5, gevent

```
root@debian-512mb-nyc3-01:~/musicbot# python3 main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
    from bot import bot
  File "/root/musicbot/bot.py", line 7, in <module>
    from database import db, text_search
  File "/root/musicbot/database.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pymongo
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/__init__.py", line 92, in <module>
    from pymongo.connection import Connection
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/connection.py", line 39, in <module>
    from pymongo.mongo_client import MongoClient
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 46, in <module>
    from pymongo import (auth,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pymongo import thread_util
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/thread_util.py", line 31, in <module>
    from gevent.lock import BoundedSemaphore as GeventBoundedSemaphore
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gevent/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    from gevent.hub import get_hub, iwait, wait
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gevent/hub.py", line 282
    except Exception, ex:
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
root@debian-512mb-nyc3-01:~/musicbot#
```

Comment: [Gevent support in Python3](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32734066/2301450)

Comment: `except Exception, ex:` should be `except Exception as ex:`

Comment: It's unclear which gevent version you're using. As gevent moved to python 3 compatibility, lines like the one that's giving you an error should not exists, making it likely that you're using an older gevent version. Use a [virtual environment](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) and install everything through pip.Just note that python3's virtualenv handling is a bit different than python2 so google the proper instructions on how to set this up.